# How to get SQL query for query with Subquery?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a query

```
q = Product.objects \
    .annotate(t=Subquery(Purchase.objects.filter(user=user)))
```

and when I do `print(q.query)` I get the following exception:

> {FieldError} Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field

What to do and why they can't resolve the expression type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.values`, to select the field you want to annotate from user

```
q = Product.objects.annotate(t=Subquery(Purchase.objects.filter(user=user).values('pk')))
```